# Fetch API: get promisestate of response

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to fetch `promiseState` of my `response`.

How do I do that?

This is my code:

```js
let my_url = 'google.com';
const txtPromise = fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=' + my_url).then(resp => resp.text());


console.log(txtPromise); //showing Promise {<pending>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async await for that:

```js
async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  );
  if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.text();
    console.log(data);
  }
}

getData();
```